# Help me to find convergence interval for this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n} + (-3)^{n}}{\ln(n+1)} \cdot(x+5)^{n}$$
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are your thoughts and what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: it converges if $$4|x+5|<1$$

Comment: @projectilemotionI try to find lim for a(n)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you explain how you find this?

Comment: @YaroslavZghurovskyi **What**? What does that mean, anyway? What limit are you talking about?

Comment: @DonAntonio Calculate limit to establish convergence

Comment: @YaroslavZghurovskyi What limit to calculate in order to establish convergence??

Comment: @DonAntonio Limit of a(n)

Comment: @YaroslavZghurovskyi Oh, dear....and what in the name of Isaac Asimov do you call a(n) to?! Have you even noticed I already wrote an answer almost 9 minutes ago?

Comment: @DonAntonio I answered the question of "projectilemotionl" and I noticed that you helped me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fill in details in the following*:

Cauchy-Hadamard Formula:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{4^n+(-3)^n}{\log(n+1)}\right|}=4\cdot\frac{\sqrt[n]{\left|1+\left(\frac{-3}4\right)^n\right|}}{\sqrt[n]{\log(n+1)}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}4\cdot\frac11=4$$

and thus the radius is $\;R=\cfrac14\;$